# Can this be serialized with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I recently came across protobuf-net and I've found it's a great alternative to using things like BinaryFormatter. That being said I was wondering if it's possible to serialize the data created by the following code with protobuf-net.

```
public Dictionary<int, object> property = new Dictionary<int, object>();

public object this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (property.ContainsKey(index))
        {
            return property[index];
        }

        return null;
    }

    private set
    {
        property[index] = value;
    }
}
```

I got the code from another example on stack overflow that doesn't relate to protobuf, or serialization in any way.

I want to be-able to write the dictionary to a file, but it won't serialize it.

I'm extremely new to protobuf-net and C# in general so if this is too broad of question please let me know what other information you'd need to know.

Comment: `...possible to serialize the following code` *code* in classes isnt serialized, the data is.  That dictionary will be a problem though since nothing (that I know of) can serialize `Object`

Comment: So the answer would be no?

Comment: It will serialize a Dictionary but not one containing objects.  Usually in NET you use a more specific type (Car, Animal, Product, Message etc) than `Object`

Comment: I realize that I was just wondering if there was any way to serialize that specific dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

protobuf-net *hates* `object` with a passion. There is a kinda-working API that *sometimes* works, but not in the context of a dictionary. The most reasonable answer would be: "no, it isn't going to help you with that".